# Vuejs v-for not working with my data, is my data not formatted correctly?

Tags: vue.js, loops, v-for

[image: Code screenshot of a v-for not working with my data]

Not sure why the data is showing up as undefined. Is the data not formatted correctly? I've tried several ways to adjust it and nest it differently but nothing is working out so far.

```
<template>
  <main>
    <AboutMeComponent v-for="i in about" :key="i.posts.id" :title="i.posts.title" :body="i.posts.body" :skills="i.posts.skills"
      :img="i.images.img" />
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import AboutMeComponent from '../components/AboutMeComponent.vue';
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      about: {
        posts: [
          { id: 1, title: "About Me", body: `Body 1` },
          { id: 2, title: "Skills"  },
          { id: 3, title: "Hobbies", body: "Body 3" },
        ],
        images: [
           { img: 'figma.png'},
           { img: 'figma.png'},
           { img: 'figma.png'},
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  components: {
    AboutMeComponent
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are need to set the `v-for` loop on the `about.posts`, not on the about. Also, if the img is used for the post, I would suggest you keep them with the post, instead of separated.

So your data will be:

```
 data() {
    return {
      about: {
        posts: [
          { id: 1, title: 'About Me', body: 'Body 1', img: 'figma.png' },
          { id: 2, title: 'Skills', body: 'Body 2', img: 'figma.png'  },
          { id: 3, title: 'Hobbies', body: 'Body 3', img: 'figma.png' },
        ],
      }
    }
  },
```

And now you can loop over `about.posts`:

```
<AboutMeComponent v-for="post in about.posts" :key="post.id" :title="post.title" :body="post.body" :img="post.img" />
```

I left `skills` out, as they are not in your data.

Just a small suggestion: using variable names as `i` makes your code harder to understand. If you had used `about in about`, you would have felt that this was not what you wanted, because you wanted something to do with a `post in posts`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

***Few Observations :***

- As each `img` in the `images` array corresponds to each object in the `posts` array. Merge that into a single one and then use v-for loop for `about.posts`.
- As few properties are missing. Use [`Optional chaining (?.)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator so that you can read the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.

Live Demo **:**

```js
Vue.component('aboutmecomponent', {
  props: ['key', 'title', 'body', 'skills', 'img'],
  template: '<h3>{{ title }}</h3>'
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    about: {
      posts: [
        { id: 1, title: "About Me", body: "Body 1" },
        { id: 2, title: "Skills"  },
        { id: 3, title: "Hobbies", body: "Body 3" },
      ],
      images: [
        { img: 'figma.png'},
        { img: 'figma.png'},
        { img: 'figma.png'},
      ]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.about.posts = this.about.posts.map((obj, index) => {
        const newObj = {
        ...obj,
        ...this.about.images[index] }
      return newObj;  
    });
    delete this.about.images;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <AboutMeComponent
                    v-for="item in about.posts"
                    :key="item?.id"
                    :title="item?.title"
                    :body="item?.body"
                    :skills="item?.skills"
                    :img="item?.img" >
  </AboutMeComponent>
</div>
```